# SQL get JSOn string value column starts with number

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, t-sql

How to get a value of column which starts with Number. Example:

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{      "1Property1" :"shiva",     "Property2" :"here ",     "metadata-department": "A",     "metadata-group": "B" }';
```

here propertyname starts with number 1.

I need a solution to get value in sql server

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of [delimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and you could do this:

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{      "1Property1" :"shiva",     "Property2" :"here ",     "metadata-department": "A",     "metadata-group": "B" }';

SELECT Item
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Text, '"')
WHERE Item LIKE '[0-9][a-zA-Z]%';
```

Results:

```
Item
-----------
1Property1
```

**QUICK UPDATE BASED ON YOUR RESPONSE:**

I don't have a SQL 2016 box at the moment so I can't use JSON_VALUE. Here's the Microsoft page that will help you with that: [JSON Data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server). Below is a good pre-SQL 2016 solution to get all the column names and associated fields:

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
  '{      "1Property1" :"shiva",     "Property2" :"here ",     "metadata-department": "A",     "metadata-group": "B" }';

WITH 
split1 AS
(
  SELECT Item = REPLACE(REPLACE(Item, '}', ''), '"', '')
  FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_2012(SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('"', @Text), 10000), ',')
),
split2 AS
(
  SELECT
    s1.Item, 
    ColName = MAX(CASE ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN s2.item END),
    ColVal  = MAX(CASE ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN s2.item END)
  FROM split1 s1
  CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_2012(s1.Item, ':') s2
  GROUP BY s1.Item
)
SELECT 
  ColName = LTRIM(RTRIM(ColName)),
  ColVal  = LTRIM(RTRIM(colVal))
FROM split2;
```

Results:

```
ColName              ColVal
-------------------- ------
metadata-department  A
metadata-group       B
Property2            here
1Property1           shiva
```

To get just the one where "columns" begin with a number you would include:

```
WHERE colname LIKE '[0-9]%';
```

Comment: need to extract data using JSON_VALUE, not just getting the column name

Comment: Thanks. This works, but i was looking at using JSON_Value function, i have been struggling to find a solution if the Name starts with number in name value pair of JSON. The work around i did is to append string to all the Names starts with Number and then make use of JSON parser of SQL. it helped me solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

if you have SQL Server 2016,Just use:

```
SELECT Value
FROM OPENJSON(@Text) 
WHERE [Key] = '1Property1'
```

Comment: Based on the OP requirement the WHERE clause would be: WHERE [key] LIKE '[0-9]%'

Comment: Thanks, it was useful.